# How can I speed up UISnapBehavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit-dynamics

I can easily make the snapping **slower** by adding a UIDynamicItemBehavior with resistance. However, the default value for resistance is 0.0, which is still too slow for me. Setting the resistance to a negative value has no effect, it seems move as fast as 0.0.

**How can I make the UISnapBehavior faster?**

(Here is an example of making the snapping **slower**):

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicItemBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button]];
dynamicItemBehavior.resistance = 50.0; // This makes the snapping SLOWER
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:button snapToPoint:point];
[self.animator addBehavior:button.dynamicItemBehavior];
[self.animator addBehavior:button.snapBehavior];
```

Comment: where does the "snapped" item start ? By increasing the distance between start and destination, you'll increase the speed

Comment: Thanks @KIDdAe , that's a good idea, it might work for my use case this time, but it would still be nice to be able to speed up the snapping speed itself, maybe by specifying duration somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use a `UIAttachmentBehavior` to achieve a similar affect as `UISnapBehavior`, with greater control over speed. For example:

```
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:viewToAnimate attachedToAnchor:viewToAnimate.center];
[self.animator addBehavior:attachment];
attachment.frequency = 20.0;
attachment.damping = 1.0;
attachment.anchorPoint = newPoint;
```

By increasing `frequency` to values above `1.0` will make it faster. By decreasing `frequency` to values between `0.0` and `1.0`, will make it slower (or by adding `resistance` values greater than `1.0` to your `UIDynamicItemBehavior`).

---

If you find it oscillating at that final location when using this `frequency` value, add some resistance to the item, too:

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *resistance = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewToAnimate]];
resistance.resistance = 100.0;
[self.animator addBehavior:resistance];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way to stop the item from oscillating once it has reached the anchor point? The snap will animate to the point and then stop. This seems to animate to the point but never stop oscillating.

Comment: @Fogmeister You can add some large resistance to the item and that will eliminate the oscillation.